# How to load module functions in custom Drupal theme

Tags: module, drupal-7

I'm not familiarly working with Drupal module. I installed,configured vegas module. There no problem in module. My actual question is how to i fetch module's PHP function in my custom.

For instance, vegas module only work on existing theme but it not working on my current theme (A known issue). I printed all images from inside vagas module and it gave me expected result.

```
print_r($backgrounds); 



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/vegas/slider1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/vegas/slider1_0.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [src] => http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/vegas/slider1_1.jpg
        )

)
```

My bad part is i cannot print that array inside my custom theme. How to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Only the functions defined in module's .module file can be invoked from the theme. Please check if the function you are trying to use is in any other file of module.

Comment: Is there any possible way available to load .module files function in page.tpl.php file

Comment: That function is in one module called vegas

Comment: Try to call the function straight away.